# How to guide bots to which thumbnail to download from my URL?

Tags: html, metadata, thumbnails, facebook-opengraph

Lots of sites these days are able to extract the most appropriate thumbnail from a URL. For example, here it finds the picture of a headless Superman: [image: example from Facebook status updater]
  for example,
[from this article](http://www.newstatesman.com/steven-baxter/2012/10/superman-vs-blogosphere).

Suppose that I want to control which thumbnail bots like this fetch for my URL, can I do that with a HTML meta tag or something?
In particular my page that I have in mind does not have a picture that is bigger than all the others.

I'm sure there isn't a solid standard but perhaps there's a decent convention that I can tap in to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this inbetween the `<head></head>` tags.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

[Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/)